# Concurrent Program in C ( can't get a proper output answer from method)

Tags: c, concurrency, pipe

I only gave the main method code. I explained my problem in code comments.

My issue is,

I try to run a method in child process and it works... but it returns a gibberish string full of random symbols.

Someone may say i didn't allocate memory to the method return but I did. I also allocated memory for the return variable in inputReader method.

Anyone know why this problem is happening?

Please ignore that im just reading one argument from terminal, im just doing that because I want to fix this issue before I add more lines to the code.

Note: The method used is about 150 lines... i have it as a different program and when i run it by itself it outputs every correctly and works. But when I try to use it in this program it doesn't return the answer i expect for some reason.

Code:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
      int     fd0[2], nbytes;
      pid_t   pid;
      ssize_t errorfi;

      char    readbuffer[9999],msg[9999];

      char** k = malloc(550);
      pipe(fd0);        

      pid = fork();

      if( pid < 0 ) {
        perror("bad fork");
        exit(0);
      }
      else if(pid == 0) {       //child process

        close(fd0[0]);

        // inputReader opens argv[1] (file) and finds all words
        // then finds all unique words
        // then returns char** p as a string containing:
        // filename, w1, w2, w3, uniquewords(int)
        // w1-w3 are the 3 most unique words with the highest freq 
        // found in the file
        k = inputReader(argv[1]); // PROBLEM HERE

        errorfi = write(fd0[1], k, 9999);  // write to pipe

         if (errorfi < 0 ) {

           fprintf (stderr, "errorfi = %d\n", errorfi);
           fprintf (stderr, "error writting texto1 in fd0 pipe %s\n",strerror(errorfi));
           exit(0);
         }

      exit(0);
     }
     else if(pid > 0) { //parent process

       close(fd0[1]);
       wait(NULL);
       nbytes = read(fd0[0], readbuffer, sizeof(readbuffer));
        printf("text received in parent from child trough pipe (%d) :%s\n", nbytes, readbuffer); 
       // returns pipe... readbuffer: returns " e�>� "
     }

return(0);

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is the variable `k`. It is declared has `char **` so it is a pointer to a pointer to `char`. And it is compliant with what I understand of the function `inputReader`. That function (not method! function you are in C, there is no method) returns an array of strings (filename, etc). So what you have in the memory pointed by `k` is an array of pointer to `char` (string if you prefer, but remember there is no string in C). You then write `k`(the pointers actually) to the pipe, which is a non-sense has addresses can't be shared among process. So what you get in the parent is the value of pointers (address to memory that doesn't represent something in the parent) written as chars (gibberish as you said).

So you need to write the strings by yourself. For the filename for example:

```
write(fd0[1],k[0],strlen(k[0])+1); // write the "string" pointed by k[0]
```

The problem now is to read this correctly because in the parent you don't know the length to read... You must decode what you have read, locate the end of each string and copy it to a buffer somewhere.

Comment: What if i copy all contents from k and concatenate it into a string with spaces and make it an array of chars?

Comment: Then send it into the pipe

Comment: You are free to use anything you want. What you need is called serialization (see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Serialization), you can use any serialization format you want, choose one that makes things easier for you.